# Adding local jar (oracle driver) to Maven and Bamboo

Tags: java, git, oracle, maven, bamboo

I need to use the oracle database driver (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver) for a project but Oracle does not have a Maven repository for it, so the only way that I have found is to download it onto my machine and then "install" the .jar to Maven as seen in [this article](http://javadevcorner.com/maven-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-to-repository/).

However, now it is time to add the project to my work's Bamboo build server, but of course the build fails because it can't find the oracle driver.

My question is: how is this sort of thing generally handled? There doesn't seem to be a way to "add" a .jar to a Bamboo build and then point Maven on Bamboo to that .jar. Another alternative that I'm trying is putting the oracle .jar on an internal git repository but I don't know how to point Maven to pull a .jar from a git repository (my current understanding is that maven repos and git repos are different thing entirely).

Any tips or suggestions appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to set up a Nexus/Artifactory on a server. This server is used for the built artifacts (your Bamboo deploys the EARs/WARs/JARs to it), to proxy external repositories (not necessary, but will speed up things) and to manage third party jars that are not available elsewhere.

In your `settings.xml` you just point to this Nexus/Artifactory and do the same for the Bamboo.

Comment: Thanks, turned out we do have Nexus set up but no one in my immediate area was aware of this.